# How should I handle in app payment for new app that does not have anything to show yet

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I have created a new app that is not in both stores yet.  It is supposed to charge users subscriptions every 1 / 3 / or 6 months.  The app helps users find nearby users based on some criteria.  Some parts of the app are for paid members and other parts of the app for all users.  There are 0 users in the app right now. So there are no users to show to each user. Which makes it difficult to charge people subscription.

I have the following questions that would appreciate if someone can answer:

- Should I show the paywall to the users at this point?
- What is the best way to make all users paid so that they can use the app even though they did not pay anything.
- What would be the best way to show the paywall to the users at this early stage.

Please keep in mind that users are the assets in this app.  So if there are no users in the app, there would be nothing to show to other users and charging people subscription would not make sense.

What would be the best strategy here.

I appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I show the paywall to the users at this point?

Sure, why not, as earlier you implement the feature, easier will be the changes in the future screens if you have a reusable logic.

> What is the best way to make all users paid so that they can use the app even though they did not pay anything.

You need to handle the access control of each feature or screen in the App that you want to be allowed only for premium access, something like:

```
if(isPremium) {
  return UnauthorizedScreen() or SubscribeNowScreen();
}

return PremiumFeatureScreen();
```

EDIT: It seems i missunderstood the question, I would focus on acquiring users in the beggining and monetizing the App with premium features instead unless you will be able to market and you company have a big name that can attract users even without have they using the app yet. You can put limitations in the app, or you can offer longer free trial period such as 1 year?

This [article](https://inoxoft.com/blog/how-to-monetize-an-app-7-best-strategies-examples/) is quite interesting on how to monetize Applications.

> What would be the best way to show the paywall to the users at this early stage.

I Recommend you to add the option to subscribe in the Options of your App, so the users can go there and subscribe if they want. [Apollo](https://apolloapp.io/) is one the Apps i like the Subscription model so you can get some ideas from this App.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I don't think you understood the second question.  Let me explain.  Since the app is new and I don't have users yet, I am thinking that I should make all users use the app for free.  The app needs to have lots of users to show to the other users.  So without having users, there is nothing to show to each user. So what is the best thing to do here?

Comment: Oh okay, i see what you mean, i would focus on acquiring users in the beggining and monetizing the App with premium features instead unless you will be able to market and you company have a big name that can attract users even without have they using the app yet.

You can put limitations in the app, or you can offer free trial of a year, something like that, i will edit my response.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  So let us say that I did market for the app through facebook and instagram to get users to come and use the app, how do you give users free trial period?  Let us say I am using RevenueCat to handle in app purchase for subscriptions.

Comment: Also while the user is in free trial ,do I need to show him/her the paywall?

Comment: Yes, they need to subscribe to the Trial and they will be billed once the trial ends via App Store or Google Play Store. The trial is configured in the Paywall itself. You gotta search the documentation of RevenueCat but for example this one here: https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/ios-products

Comment: Again thanks for your help.  Do you think have free trial of 1 year for the first users would be a fair thing to do since those customers would not have other users to view?

Comment: I cant really say how many time is appropriated since i dont have domain knowledge of your business, but definitely worthy to attract new users.